# Move item in json array

Tags: javascript, json

I have json object like this

```
[
  { "id":"1", "item1":"item1 text","item2":"item2text","item3":"item3text" },
  { "id":"2", "item1":"item1 text","item2":"item2text","item3":"item3text" }
]
```

My question is I want to move id 2 to first position through a function by passing the id of the element. like

```
function movetotop(id){
  //Code here to move id 2 to the top position 
}
```

Hope someone help.

regards

Comment: You mean you have a Javascript array with two Javascript objects inside? There's no JSON here.

Comment: yeah I only pasted the object data, not the whole object.

Comment: This edit might be wrong, then. Is this an array of objects? [ {}, {} ] or an object containing other objects? { "item1" : {}, "item2": {} }

Answer (score 4):

```
function moveIdToTop(jsonarray, id) {
 for (var i = 0; i < jsonarray.length; ++i) {
    if (jsonarray[i].id == id) {
       var temp = jsonarray[i];
       jsonarray.splice(i, 1);
       jsonarray.unshift(temp);
       break;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: And if you can tell me how to remove the same from array.

Comment: means I can pass the id and it removes from the array.

Comment: function will move object with passed id on first index

Comment: yeah thank you for that. I am asking for a function which removes the item from the array if I pass the respective ID.

Comment: for this purpose delete this line: jsonarray.unshift(temp);

Comment: Sorry to bother you again,

I have two json objects. I want to merge them in one. How can I achieve that ?

Like

[
  { "id":"1", "item1":"item1 text","item2":"item2text","item3":"item3text" },
  { "id":"2", "item1":"item1 text","item2":"item2text","item3":"item3text" }
]

into

[
  { "id":"1", "item1":"item1 text","item2":"item2text","item3":"item3text" },
  { "id":"2", "item1":"item1 text","item2":"item2text","item3":"item3text" },
  { "id":"1", "item1":"item1 text","item2":"item2text","item3":"item3text" },
  { "id":"2", "item1":"item1 text","item2":"item2text","item3":"item3text" }
]

Answer (score 2):

If you have an array of objects, use the sort method:

```
var data = [
 { "id":"1", "item1":"item1 text","item2":"item2text","item3":"item3text" },
 { "id":"2", "item1":"item1 text","item2":"item2text","item3":"item3text" }
];

var sorted = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id < b.id;
});
```

This will move 2 to the top. Tweak the sort function to match your needs.

Comment: -1 the question is not to sort the items of the array, is to move from one place to the top of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that they are in an array, [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8eezW/3/):

```
function popTop(arr, id) {
    var i, al = arr.length;
    dance: for (i = 0; i < al; i++) {
        if (arr[i].id == id) {
            arr.unshift(arr.splice(i, 1)[0]);
            break dance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: cute. But labels? You're a bad person. :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the element from the array and re-insert it as the first one.

```
var yourarray = [{ "id":"1", "item1":"item1 text","item2":"item2text","item3":"item3text" }, 
                 { "id":"2", "item1":"item1 text","item2":"item2text","item3":"item3text" }];

function movetotop(id){
    //Code here to move id 2 to the top position
    var index = yourarray.map(function(element){return element.id;}).indexOf(id);
    if (index > -1) {
        var extracted = yourarray.splice( index,1 )[0];
        yourarray.unshift(extracted);
    }
}
```

Use with `movetotop('2');`

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/NGjXy/